# Error in Scriptresource.axd on line 1072

Tags: c#-4.0, internet-explorer-8, ajaxcontroltoolkit, scriptmanager, scriptresource.axd

I built an app and it works well on other browsers but in IE I get this error

Web page error details

> Message: Invalid argument. Line: 1072 Char: 17 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://mylocalsite.com:2213/ScriptResource.axd?d=1tDu57dDaZKXqeUMRLfpHIRMgzFEPzH2bBPyO5T7sKgmV8TaXlX87X4yrzotsxJuFatqNWiskMSyTy0_gHByrPvaUwuplgHFESMaD5c4STZZT7gS12UIJwx7C0O_1V6PuTcuqN428QAt2Wo565IlXQ2&t=7f16157c

I get this error when you open any page on the site at the bottom of the IE status bar.

How can one sort this out? Is this related to AjaxControlToolKit or the ScriptManager?

Answer (score 0):

i found the source of the  problem so i wish to post it for someone else just in case

it was the HtmlEditorExtender for AjaxControlToolkit. as soon as i removed the HtmlEditorExtender the error above disappeared. Now i have to find another way of incorporating it.